# How to solve private boolean error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The code containing the error is:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

 bottomNavigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation);
        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(navigation);

    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener navigation =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                    switch (item.getItemId())
                    {
                        case R.id.home:
                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "HOME", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;

                        case R.id.category:
                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "CATEGORY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;

                }
            };
}
```

It is possible to see the error in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJpHR.png).

The code shows a Toast with the text corresponding to the selected view.

Comment: `onNavigationItemReselected` returns void not `boolean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `OnNavigationItemReselectedListener` listener.
The method [**`onNavigationItemReselected`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener) has to return `void` instead of `boolean`.

Maybe you are looking for  [`BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) listener.

Comment: yeah, i change reselected to selected and it's work....hahaha...thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Check your category id in menus file first. Its containing or not

Comment: Yes, it has in my menus

Comment: Ok pls try to change id like category to category_id